# Is it possible to replace certain URLs with others in https requests from applications in Android?

Tags: android, https, urlconnection

Is it possible to locally create some kind of 'man-in-the-middle' replacement from an original https request from an Android app, to any other url?

I know this involves a lot of possibly shady security problems, but I would like to easily test my app with a 'testing' API, therefore I would like all the requests to the main API to instead go to the testing api, which should work without problems in theory since they work in the same way.

The idea would be that since most apps use Android's UrlConnection library or a variant of that, a rooted phone could alter those libs to allow changing any request going to 'api.prod.domain.com' to 'api.test.domain.com', or any other request parameters for that matter.

Is there anthing available on that front?

Comment: can't you just change your domain/endpoint in your app code?

Comment: Sure, I'll probably do that in the end, but since I didn't want to install several apps, one for each environment, I wanted to know if there was this kind of quick'n'dirty fix

Comment: There sure is! Checkout product flavors https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html in gradle, where you can set the url depending on your flavor (test/production)